# Probability Application with Combinatorics

Tags: probability-theory

There are a number of probability applications I've seen where we have some fixed number of $x$'s and want to figure out how many possible ways we can, say, divide them into $y$ groups. Suppose, for example, we have $10$ $x$'s and want to divide these into $4$ distinct groups, and want to know how many ways we can do this. With $10$ $x$'s and $3$ dividers, this ends up being, if I'm not mistaken, ${13 \choose 3}$.

I know this follows mechanically, but I don't quite understand the logic behind it. Specifically, the logic seems to be that there are $10 + 3$ ways to place the dividers. Starting before the first $x$, though, in which case we would have $0$ elements in every group but the last, I just can't count $13$.

This is a bit trivial, but the way I'm counting is, if we arrange the $10$ $x$'s in a row:

(1) Before the first x (everything goes in the forth group)

(2) After the first, before the second

(3) After the second, before the third

(4) After the third, before the fourth

(5) After the fourth, before the fifth

(6) After the fifth, before the sixth

(7) After the sixth, before the seventh

(8) After the seventh, before the eighth

(9) After the eight, before the ninth

(10) After the ninth, before the tenth

(11) After the tenth ((everything goes in the first group)

I'm not sure how we'd end up with $13$ from this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suppose we have 13 objects in a line.  If we treat 3 of them as walls, they will divide the remaining 10 objects into 3 groups.  So the number of divisions is simply the number of ways to choose the walls.

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: You seem to be confusing the case where we have one divider with the case where we have multiple dividers.  Certainly, it is hard to see where the number $13$ comes from if we only have one divider.  Indeed, in the case where we have only one divider, there are eleven (*not thirteen*) places where it could be exactly as you (*quite tediously*) outline.  The point though is that after we place the first divider and wish to place a second divider we will have *more* available places which if you again list out will be twelve possibilities, and a 13th possibility when you go to place the third.

Comment: But then, in the process of counting in this fashion by placing one divider after another, you will have been treating the dividers differently... for example by letting them have different colors.  We then need to recognize that with $3$ dividers and $3!$ different arrangements of the dividers, we will have overcounted every arrangement we wanted to count by a factor of $3!$, giving $\frac{11\cdot 12\cdot 13}{3!}=\binom{13}{3}$ such arrangements in the case of three dividers.